# How can I implement a method that accepts a Consumer<Optional<T>> that is contravariant in T?

Tags: java, generics, generic-variance

In the following sample, I can pass a `Consumer<Optional<Integer>` to `foo`, but not a `Consumer<Optional<Number>>`.  On the other hand, I can pass either type to `foo2`, but then I can't call the accept method of the consumer from the method body.  Is there a way to change the `foo` method so that this works?  My initial intuition was to try `void foo(Consumer<Result<? super T>> c)` but that apparently doesn't mean what I would assume.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class test<T> {

    public void foo(Consumer<Optional<T>> c) {
        Optional<T> t = null;
        c.accept(t); // compiles
    }

    public void foo2(Consumer<? extends Optional<? super T>> c) {
        Optional<T> t = null;
        c.accept(t); // doesn't compile
    }

    public static void bar() {
        test<Integer> t = null;
        Consumer<Optional<Number>> crn = null;
        Consumer<Optional<Integer>> cri = null;

        t.foo(cri); // compiles
        t.foo(crn); // doesn't compile

        t.foo2(cri); // compiles
        t.foo2(crn); // compiles
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `Optional` isn't special from the point of view of the type system: *we* know that `Optional` only has a provider method (`Optional.get()`) and that it has no consumer methods (like `Optional.set(T)`); but the compiler doesn't.

So, the compiler it won't let you pass an `Optional<Integer>` where an `Optional<Number>` is required: it is preventing you from ever calling that mythical `set` method, in case you passed in a `Double` instead of an `Integer`.

The only way around this is to change the `Optional<T>` into an `Optional<S>`, where `S` is a supertype of `T`. You can do this by either:

- Casting - which you know is safe, because of the immutability of `Optional` and its lack of consumer methods; but you get an unchecked warning (which is actually fine to suppress, because of the properties of `Optional`).
- Creating a new `Optional` of the right type - maybe more pure, but has the runtime overhead of creating the new instance.

In order to write such a thing in a method, you would have to write it as a static method (probably in the `test` class, but it could be elsewhere); Java's type system isn't expressive enough to be able to write the required constraints on an instance method's signature:

```
public static <T, S extends T> void foo3(Consumer<Optional<T>> c, test<S> test) {
    Optional<S> s = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // Safe because of properties of Optional.
    Optional<T> t = (Optional<T>) (Optional<?>) s;

    c.accept(t);
}
```

and invoke like this (using the values of `cri`, `crn` and `t` from the question code):

```
foo3(cri, t); // compiles
foo3(crn, t); // compiles
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Jqi9y0)