# How to upcast object contained in Java 8 Optional?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, java-8, option-type

Is there an efficient way to perform upcasting while using an Optional object.
Here is a sample code:

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}

B func(){
    //do something
    return new B();
}

Optional<B> func2(){
    //do something
    return Optional.of(new B());
}

main() {
    A a = func(); // Upcasting works fine
    B b = func(); // Upcasting works fine
    Optional<B> b = func2(); // 1. Works fine
    Optional<A> a = func2(); // 2. How to make this work ?
}
```

(2.) gives an error. I can solve it by creating another function.

But is there an efficient way, so that func2() can be used for both (1.) and (2.) ?

Comment: This is not upcasting

Comment: `Optional<A>` is not a supertype of `Optional<B>` in your example, which is why that is not upcasting.

Comment: FYI, this is one reason why Scala chose to support declaration-site variance rather than use-site variance.

Comment: "Efficient" would probably be `(Optional<A>) (Optional<?>) func2()`. This generates an unchecked cast a warning, but is safe because of the properties of `Optional` (specifically: it is immutable, and has no consumer methods). [I wrote this related answer earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842017/3788176).

Comment: Simply try it with `Optional<? extends A> a = func2()`.

Comment: @Vatsal can you clarify what you mean by "efficient"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would write a method like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // Safe. See below.
static <T> Optional<T> copyOf(Optional<? extends T> opt) {
  return (Optional<T>) opt;
}
```

(If you don't like the name `copyOf`, see my comment about Guava's `ImmutableList` below)

This is very efficient in terms of runtime speed: the cast gets elided at compile time:

```
static <T> java.util.Optional<T> copyOf(java.util.Optional<? extends T>);
    Code:
       0: aload_0  # Read the parameter.
       1: areturn  # Return the parameter.
```

so the only cost is that of a method call; this is easily done away with by the JIT.

You can then invoke like:

```
Optional<A> a = copyOf(func2());
```

---

This is safe because `Optional` has the following property: it is guaranteed not to have any state changes caused by setter methods taking parameters dependent upon the type variable `T`. Phew. Quite a mouthful. I'll make it more concrete.

Because `Optional`

1. has no setter methods (of any kind, but more generally none that take parameters of type `T`, `SomeGenericType<T>` etc)
2. is `final` (so you can't subclass it to add a setter to violate the previous point)

there is nothing you can do to the value held by the `Optional<T>` (or lack thereof) that will make it *not* an instance of `T` (or lack thereof).

And because every instance of `T` is also an instance of its superclasses, there is nothing unsafe about:

```
SuperclassOfT s = optionalOfT.get();
```

As such, this method is type safe (it will fail if you've invoked it on a non-present optional; but that's not a type error).

You will find similar code in [Guava's `ImmutableList.copyOf`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#L253) (the inspiration for calling it "`copyOf`" above, even though it's not really a copy). There, there *are* setter methods (like `add`), but those methods immediately throw `UnsupportedOperationException`s, and thus do not affect the list's state.

---

Note that whilst immutable types have the necessary properties described above to make such a cast safe, the type does not necessarily need to be immutable to perform the cast safely.

For example, you could have an `ErasableOptional<T>` type, which has an `erase()` method on it which, when called, converted a "present" value into an "absent" value (i.e. `get()` no longer succeeds). It would be safe to cast such an instance to an `ErasableOptional<SupertypeOfT>` because the value is either a `T` or absent; you can't make it *not* an instance of `SupertypeOfT` or absent.

Comment: Why not using `map` and cast the value inside instead of casting the optional? I think that by *efficient* OP means easy...

Comment: @Federico because that will create a new instance. I disagree with your assessment of OP's intent (whilst acknowledging it as a possibility; and that we shouldn't be second guessing): when people say "efficient", there is the connotation of "fastest", "least memory" etc; they will ask explicitly for "easy" or "straightforward" if simplicity is the goal.

Comment: Point taken. If OP said *efficient*, let's stick to efficient. Nice analysis, btw.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: you wouldn’t need a cast, just `Optional<A> a = func2() .map(Function.identity());` would do the job. But Andy is right, this would create a new object, unless the JVM optimizes it away. Which one is more efficient, depends on the actual metric.

Answer (score 8):

Optional is, quote from java doc:

> a container object which may or may not contain a non-null value....
>   Additional methods that depend on the presence or absence of a
>   contained, such as orElse() ...

As we can see Optional container, uses generic type to define which object to contain.

```
Optional <T>
```

so you can do this:

```
Optional<? extends A> a = func2(); // 2. Upcasting Will work :)
```

and to access the optional object a an object of type A :

```
a.get();
```

Comment: Should work in most cases, but when using `.orElseGet(() -> new A())`, you would need to add a `.map(Function.<A>identity())` or a `.map((A a) -> a)` before doing the orElseGet, because otherwise the compiler will get mad.

Answer (score 7):

You can try using a mapping function:

```
Optional<A> oa = func2().map(v -> (A) v);
```

Note that you don't really need to put the `(A)` cast there, but it makes it a little clearer what's going on.

Comment: Java uses `->` for lambda expressions. Besides that, the type cast is unnecessary. `Optional<A> oa = func2().map(v -> v);` would work, also replacing `v -> v` with `Function.identity()` would work.

Comment: You could use `.map((A v) -> v)` instead, since that is type-safe.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this I think would be `Optional<A> a = func2().flatMap(Optional::of)` or `Optional<A> a = func2().map(Function.identity())` because both do not require casting and only use existing functionality.