# Casting type inside Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have the following:

```
class Foo implements Inter {
    void doSomething();
}

Optional<Inter> getPossible() {
    Optional<Foo> possible = ...;
    possible.ifPresent(Foo::doSomething);
    return possible.map(f -> f);
}
```

`getPossible` needs to return an `Optional<Inter>` because it's overriding a superclass's implementation.

That map at the end of the method is purely to convert the type. Is there a more elegant option?

Comment: Is there a reason for `possible` not being of `Optional<Inter>` type in the first place?

Comment: Yes. The code in `ifPresent` needs the type. Will expand to demonstrate.

Comment: You could return an Optional<? extends Inter>, and remove the map().

Comment: @JBNizet Ah yes that did it. thanks.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852936/how-to-upcast-object-contained-in-java-8-optional

Answer (score 9):

To make clear that you only need casting, you can use Class::cast with .map:

```
class Foo implements Inter {
    void doSomething();
}

Optional<Inter> getPossible() {
    Optional<Foo> possible = ...;
    possible.ifPresent(Foo::doSomething);
    return possible.map(Inter.class::cast);
}
```

Comment: The small downside of this approach is that it does unnecessary casting at runtime for a cast that will never fail.  That said, casting should be pretty cheap these days. It also makes it seem like the casting is necessary (i.e. there may be a chance where it could fail), when it's just working around a compile-time limitation.  Mapping using the identity instead of casting is just odd enough to call out that something weird is happening (or there's some redundant code that can be removed).

Answer (score 2):

Return a `Optional<? extends Inter>` instead of an `Optional<Inter>`.

Comment: If "getPossible needs to return an Optional<Inter> because it's overriding a superclass's implementation"  is true, changing the return type in a subclass to `Optional<? extends Inter>` shouldn't compile, unless you can also change the superclass

Comment: Besides that, having return types with wildcards is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Holger appreciate an alternative then

Comment: First of all, you should clarify why your solution works. As @Chirlo correctly pointed out, if the superclass declaration truly is `Optional<Inter> getPossible()`, you can’t override it with a method having the signature `Optional<? extends Inter> getPossible()`. If that works, there must be an error in your premise, which would void your entire question. Once we know your true setup, we can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to edit the method signature in `Foo` to become the following:

```
class Foo implements Inter {
    Inter doSomething() {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, you can simplify `getPossible` to the following:

```
Optional<Inter> getPossible() {
    Optional<Foo> possible = ...;
    return possible.map(Foo::doSomething);
}
```

Comment: Instead of changing the signature of `doSomething()`, you could resort to a lambda expression, `return possible.map(foo -> { foo.doSomething(); return foo; });`