# Store references to a class with a generic type parameter and its implementation with the same one

Tags: java, generics

I am using a `Map` to store references to a class of a generic type parameter and an implementation object with the same generic type parameter, more specifically:

```
public class SomeImpl<T extends BaseClass> {

    void execute(T instance);
}
```

Now, in another class, i want to store references to implementations based on their generic type parameter.

```
private Map<Class<BaseClass>, SomeImpl<BaseClass>> map;
```

However, i find it somewhat confusing to operate with the generics here, especially since a lot of unsafe cast warnings are shown.

```
private <T extends BaseClass> void register(SomeImpl<T> impl, Class<T> aClass) {
    // unsafe
    Class<BaseClass> configClass = (Class<BaseClass>) aClass; 
    // unsafe
    map.put((SomeImpl<BaseClass>) impl, configClass);
}
```

and later when i want to retrieve some instance

```
private SomeImpl<BaseClass> get(Class<? extends BaseClass> aClass) {
    // unsafe
    return (SomeImpl<BaseClass>) map.get(aClass); 
}
```

Could someone clarify if the above statements are safe, thus the warnings can safely be ignored?

Comment: What is `binder`?

Comment: @Nikolas Sorry, changed it to `impl`

Comment: What is `binders`? I suggest it's `map`.

Comment: @Nikolas Yes, it is. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Have you tried `private static void register(SomeImpl<BaseClass> impl, Class<BaseClass> aClass) { }` and `private static SomeImpl<BaseClass> get(Class<BaseClass> aClass) { }`? The map stores `BaseClass` anyway.

Comment: @Nikolas Of course, this will work fine, but then i have the unchecked casts somewhere else, when calling these methods from outside.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44422685/2891664 for examples of this kind of thing, although I don't know if you can use any of those directly since I don't know what `BaseClass` and `SomeImpl` are. I also don't know enough about your types involved to say for sure if the code in your question is type-safe or not, although it probably isn't.

Comment: @Radiodef I have posted an answer to my question that takes your suggestions into account. Could you take a look? I would mark it as accepted then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heterogeneous container to store genericly typed objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139325/heterogeneous-container-to-store-genericly-typed-objects-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i did go with the following solution. Thanks a lot to Radiodef, who pointed me to the use of an type-safe heterogeneous container.

```
private Map<Class<?>, SomeImpl<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And the following methods will add/get the concrete implementation:

```
public <T extends BaseClass> void addImpl(SomeImpl<T> loader, Class<T> aClass) {
    map.put(type, loader);
}

public <T extends BaseClass> SomeImpl<T> getImpl(Class<T> aClass) {
    return (SomeImpl<T>) map.get(type);
}
```

Originally, i was also looking for a method that can be invoked with any `BaseClass`. I  figured out that this is not possible with that pattern, so the following did the trick:

```
public SomeImpl<BaseClass> getBaseImpl(Class<? extends BaseClass> aClass) {
    return (BaseLoader<BaseClass>) map.get(type);
}
```

And this is indeed a truely unsave cast, since the compiler cannot ensure that the correct type of `BaseClass` is passed. However, i can ensure that the correct type is always passed (or force it using `isAssignableFrom`).

This allows me to load some `BaseClass` objects, from a database for example:

```
List<BaseClass> list = getSomeBaseClasses();

Map<Class<? extends BaseClass>, List<BaseClass> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BaseClass::getClass));

map.forEach((aClass, bases) -> {
    SomeImpl<BaseClass> impl = getBaseImpl(aClass);
    impls.forEach(impl::execute);
}
```

Comment: I would make your `getBaseImpl` method return `SomeImpl<? extends BaseClass>`. Like I said in my other comment, I don't know enough about what you're doing to know if casting to `SomeImpl<BaseClass>` is safe. There are some specific circumstances where a cast like that is okay (for example [see this answer which talks about casting `Optional`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853739/2891664)), but it usually isn't. You should be able to call the regular generic `getImpl` with any class argument extending `BaseClass`, though, even a wildcard like `Class<? extends BaseClass>`.

Comment: @Radiodef The problem is that i have to use the `BaseClass` (as i fetch multiple subclasses with Hibernate, i have created a minimal example [here](https://ideone.com/Q6nTgX). Currently it does not compile, since `SomeImpl<? extends BaseClass>` cannot be called with `BaseClass` as an argument.

Comment: I suppose i could open a new question as well with that.

Comment: Since the `BaseLoader` is basically a consumer, you could use a wildcard capturing helper method to call `load`, like in my answer. (I was editing the answer a bit earlier, so if you didn't see that example before, there's some extra stuff now.) Here's a fork of your Ideone example with this: https://ideone.com/j7YFCi

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was also able to find sonething similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139325/heterogeneous-container-to-store-genericly-typed-objects-in-java