# How can I safely upcast an Optional?

Tags: java, option-type

Suppose I have an `Optional<Exception>` and want to cast it to an `Optional<Throwable>`. Are there any prettier ways of doing this rather than:

```java
Optional<Exception> optionalException = Optional.of(new Exception());
Optional<Throwable> optionalThrowable = (Optional<Throwable>) (Optional<? extends Throwable>) optionalException;
```

This solution generates a lint warning in IntelliJ.

```
Unchecked cast: 'java.util.Optional<capture<? extends java.lang.Throwable>>' to 'java.util.Optional<java.lang.Throwable>'
```

Comment: "SupressWarnings("unchecked") might be better than `.map()` here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is OK, but has the downside of creating a new `Optional` instance.

An alternative is to write a utility method, in which you can suppress the warning just once:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // Safe covariant cast.
static <T> Optional<T> upcast(Optional<? extends T> opt) {
  return (Optional<T>) opt;
}
```

and then just use this in all the places without warnings.

But better (if you have the control to do so) is to fix the place where you need an `Optional<Throwable>` to accept an `Optional<? extends Throwable>`.

Comment: Did you forget you wrote this? :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853739/1898563

Comment: @Michael yep. I write lots.

Comment: In principle, the implementation of `Optional.map` could skip the creation of a new `Optional` instance when the resulting reference is identical to the old. However, the creation of an `Optional` might not be expensive enough to justify spending time on such an optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Found it:

```java
Optional<Exception> optionalException = Optional.of(new Exception());
Optional<Throwable> optionalThrowable = optionalException.map(Function.identity());
```

Comment: If you want to use `.orElseGet(() -> new Throwable())` on the optional without storing it in the intermediate `Optional<Throwable> optionalThrowable` variable, you can use `.<Throwable>map(Function.identity())` or `.map(Function.<Throwable>identity())` as a type hint. You could also use `.map((Throwable t) -> t)`. In all three cases you prevented the use of an unsafe class cast. If you do make the `Optional<Throwable> optionalThrowable` variable, you can just do `.map(t -> t)`